# Zombienet won't allow whitespaces in collator names

Tags: parachain-collator, zombienet

I am using zombienet @ v1.89 and I found that if I had a whitespace on a parachain collator name :

```
  [parachains.collator]
  name = "Cook Network"
```

Instead of passing `--name 'Cook Network'`, `--name Cook Network` is passed, causing a failure for the CLI. This led me to the question if this is a zombienet specific bug because I am not aware that whitespaces should be discouraged in collator names.

Comment: Moved to GH issue.

Answer (score 1):

I opened a bug report in the repo directly - asking here in SE is more for questions: https://github.com/paritytech/zombienet/issues/1659

Answer (score 1):

I replied to the Github issue and will figure out what the best approach is. Lets close this here and keep [tracking this in github as Oliver suggested](https://github.com/paritytech/zombienet/issues/1659).

Comment: sure <minimum comment length>

Comment: Hey @Purple_Turtle, we are thinking on replace whitespaces with dashes as a workaround for this and I want to ask you if that ok for you or you need the whitespaces in the name for some reason? Thx (note: can you reply in the issue please)

Comment: @Purple_Turtle as note, this is already fixed by https://github.com/paritytech/zombienet/issues/1659 and will be part of the next release. Thanks for your feedback!